# How to change color of a row of html table by click a button in that row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

this is my table

```
echo"<table id=\"company\">";
                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
                    {
                         $s=  $row['company_id'];
                         $r= $row['company_name'];
                         $a= $row['head_office_city'];
                        echo"<tr><td>".$r."</td><td>".$a."</td>
                        <td><a href=\"#\" class=\"topopup\" id=\"update_comp\" onClick=\"callYourPopup(".$row['company_id'].");\"><img title='update details' alt=\"Delete\" class='del' src='images/update.png'/></a> </td>

                        <td><a href=\"company_inactive.php?column1=".$row['company_id']."\"><img title='make company inactive' alt=\"Delete\" class='del' src='images/delete.png'/></a> </td></tr>";

                    }
                    echo"</table>";
                    }
```

i want to change the color when i click in image in the last column. which is the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: use javascript for that

Comment: There is nothing about PHP so please remove 'php' tag. You can solve your problem by using jQuery.

Comment: Image is in a link, so you leave the page anyway?

Comment: @user574632 link lead to company_inactive.php to just update my database and return home. while updation occurs color of this row should changed..

Comment: "while updation [sic] occurs' this suggests the browser does not refresh, so you need ajax. I suggest you look at jquery for this, there are many examples on here and google

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way it's add onclick handler to each image:

```
onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor='red'"
```

But I'm not recommend write code like this.

If you has included jQuery into project then use `$('#tableID tr td:last img').click(changeRowColor)`. Where `changeRowColor` is:

```
function () {
  $(this).closest('tr').css('background-color', 'red');
}
```

of

```
function () {
  $(this).closest('tr').addClass('colorized');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#company td a img').click(function(){
   $(this).closest('tr').addClass('changeColor');
});
```

and then use .changeColor td{background:red} to change the color of that row